# Java type inference with erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, erasure

having some problem with erasure & type inference. I have the following class hierarchy, which doesn't look very complicated:

```
public class Foo<T> {

}

public class Bar<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public Bar(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
Bar<Foo<?>> bar = new Bar<>(Foo.class);
```

which, of course, doesn't work, as Foo is not quite `Foo<?>`. The question is how to construct such a Bar? I need exactly `Bar<Foo<?>>`, not `Bar<Foo>`, as there is method which accepts only `Bar<Foo<?>>` as a parameter. Appreciate ideas.

Comment: You can cast `Foo.class` to `Class<Foo<?>>`, which might paper over the problem enough for your purposes.  (You can't _actually_ represent different generics with just `Class` objects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create generic object without providing Type information in `<>`, as shown in your question post. You must supply a Type or use the **raw** version. If you are forced to use the wild card parameter type, then just suppress the warning by using raw type, as shown below

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Bar<Foo<?>> bar = new Bar(Foo.class);       

//Bar is having no type "<>" (but this is not recommended
```

Comment: True, I didn't get the point of your answer initially. This is about as correct as the more complex suggestion.

Comment: This is an option, I assume. Wondering why I didn't try it myself :) Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there is no such `Class` object, because, as you note, erasure means that there can't be. You need to cast it:

```
((Class<Foo<?>>)(Class)Foo.class)
```

This will give you the bounds you want, but may generate a compiler warning because you are performing an unchecked generic cast. This is reasonable: the compiler is requiring you to acknowledge that you are leaving behind the compile-time safety of generics. But in this case there's really no way this case can generate a runtime error, at this point in your program or in the future, so it's fine.

The double-cast is necessary because the compiler knows that Foo.class is not compatible with Class>, so you have to first cast it to the "raw" type Class: using raw types in an expression disables the compiler's generic-type checks for that expression, so then the "impossible" cast works okay.

Answer (score 0):

Since java.lang.Class is immutable, you could use a weaker type  declaration in the constructor of Bar:

```
class Foo<T> {}

class Bar<T> {
    private final Class<? extends T> clazz;

    public Bar(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

If you'd still need the field to be of type `Class<T>` rather than `Class<? extends T>` it's safe to cast it within the constructor.